# how to create new object iterate from another array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const datax = [
        {
          hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
          hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
          hrInTotal: 1106,
          hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
          hrTotal: 10020,
          mo: 5,
          time: "Thu Jun 25 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
        },
        {
          hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
          hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
          hrInTotal: 1106,
          hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
          hrTotal: 10120,
          mo: 5,
          time: "Thu Jun 26 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
        }, {
          hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
          hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
          hrInTotal: 1106,
          hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
          hrTotal: 1020,
          mo: 5,
          time: "Thu Jun 27 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
        },
        {
          hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
          hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
          hrInTotal: 1106,
          hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
          hrTotal: 10110,
          mo: 5,
          time: "Thu Jun 28 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
        }
]
```

```
const newArray = datax.foreach((element, index) => {
        const labels = []
        const counts = []
        const idx = index
        labels[idx] = index
        counts[idx] = element.hrTotal
        return {labels, counts}
      });
```

> > > Trying to achieve below object. I want iterate above array of object and get new array of object with given result below i have tryed using foreach and i am getting error as forach is not a function .

```
 newArray = [{
               hrTatal:[1020,10110,10120,10020],
               labels:[0,1,2,3]
              }]
```

Comment: Correct syntax is "forEach" that's why you're getting the error

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `map` instead of `forEach`, like:

```js
const newArray = datax.map((element, index) => {
        const labels = []
        const counts = []
        const idx = index
        labels[idx] = index
        counts[idx] = element.hrTotal
        return {labels, counts}
      });
```

The reason is because [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything (`undefined`). [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new modified array.

Comment: while i am using foreach or map i am getting following error Uncaught TypeError: data1.map is not a function
    at LineGraphModal (index.js?4066:94)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js?61bb:14838)

Comment: The error like `Uncaught TypeError: datax.map is not a function`, could be displayed if `datax` is not an array but something else.

Comment: `data1.map is not a function at LineGraphModal (index.js?4066:94) ` is seen to be `data1` is not an array in time you call `map` prototype of it, because may be value of `data1` is assigned by asynchronous function. So you an use lodash/isEmpty to check `data1` value before use `map` prototype of it. (Like `if(!isEmpty(data1)) { data1.map() }`)

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce, define the output array inside id and append the needed properties.

```js
const datax = [{
    hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
    hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
    hrInTotal: 1106,
    hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
    hrTotal: 10020,
    mo: 5,
    time: "Thu Jun 25 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
  },
  {
    hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
    hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
    hrInTotal: 1106,
    hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
    hrTotal: 10120,
    mo: 5,
    time: "Thu Jun 26 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
  }, {
    hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
    hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
    hrInTotal: 1106,
    hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
    hrTotal: 1020,
    mo: 5,
    time: "Thu Jun 27 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
  },
  {
    hrCounts: [96, 62, 50, 68, 93, 109, 91, 66, 83, 116, 85, 101],
    hrInCounts: [95, 76, 85, 99, 105, 123, 78, 60, 96, 100, 109, 80],
    hrInTotal: 1106,
    hrLabels: [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26],
    hrTotal: 10110,
    mo: 5,
    time: "Thu Jun 28 18:30:00 UTC 2020",
  }
]


const res = datax.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  acc[0] = {
    hrTotal: [...acc[0].hrTotal, x.hrTotal],
    labels: [...acc[0].labels, i]
  }
  return acc;
}, [{
  hrTotal: [],
  labels: []
}])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: datax.reduce is not a function